# Terraform list element out of bounds?

Tags: indexing, indexoutofboundsexception, terraform

From the Terraform docs:

> element(list, index) - Returns a single element from a list at the given index. If the index is greater than the number of elements, this function will wrap using a standard mod algorithm.

What would be a good reason to wrap using mod? This behavior seems to me like it could be the cause of lots of headaches.

At the top of my head I can only remember two other approaches to handle accessing an element that's out of bounds:

- Python/Ruby: return None/Nil
- Java/JS/Ruby: Raise an error

I'm so used to them that they seem to make sense, you either get nothing or an error but why would you ever expect to get the `k mod n` element in the list? If you were the implementer, how would you justify this choice of behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shortcut for having to do the mod yourself but can be useful when looping over a short list such as the amount of subnets or availability zones that you want to put multiple instances in.

This is a pretty common pattern and appears in the [`aws_subnet_ids` data source docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html#example-usage):

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  tags {
    Tier = "Private"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "app" {
  count         = 6
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, count.index)}"
}
```

If you were to use the [slice operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-list-variables) instead you would get an index out of bounds exception as soon as you have more instances than subnets returned by the data source.